# Quick Books SDK - BillAddRq

Tags: c#, .net, quickbooks

I am having difficulties creating a `Bill` in QuickBooks via my 3rd party application developed in .NET 4.x and c# as the language. I am referencing `Interop.QBFC13.dll` I am using both the sample code provided online as well as a modified version of the sample code. There seems to be no errors thrown. However, no `Bill` is created on QB.

I do have working code that creates an `Invoice` and a `PO` that works great  that I have been using for years.

I would appreciate any insight on what could possible be preventing the Bill from being generated.​

Comment: Post your code. Post the raw XML that gets sent to QuickBooks. Post whatever you get back. We can't help you if you don't post your code.

Comment: Also, did you go through the troubleshooting list? https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/article/Troubleshooting-QuickBooks-Desktop-SDK-Issues

Comment: Language improvements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was providing both the ListID and the FullName for the vendor. The ListID I was providing was not the visible value that I thought was listed on the vendor form.

This is the XML that was sent to QB from the app:

```
<VendorRef>
<ListID>Acme Vendor 1</ListID>
<FullName>Acme Vendor 1</FullName>
</VendorRef>
```

The ListID's are invalid for the Vendor and Account.

Below are the responses from Intuit...

You can either remove those lines OR look them up and use the actual value.
They will look something like this - 8000007C-1639597013

You would need to do a VendorQuery to get the ListID.

An option for the Bill is to NOT include the ListID field and just have the FullName. Because you had both, it tried to use ListID and since that was invalid it threw the error message. You can use ListID or FullName, but if both are specified ListID will take precedence.